# My disk space got deleted

Tags: disk

Yesterday I wanted to experience some nostalgia so I installed Team Fortress 2 on my laptop, launched it and my computer froze. The keyboard wouldn't function. I could only move cursor but I couldn't click on anything. I decided to turn my computer off. When I wanted to boot back in I wasn't able to do so because all my files from the disk got deleted. I decided I would reinstall Ubuntu, but I found out that I have no space on the disk. Does anyone know what happened and how can get my disk space back?

The problem is not not enough space on the disk, but the disk itself has 0 bytes.

Results of `df -h` :

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on how “all my files from disk got deleted” and “I have no space on my disk” do not contradict each other? Is your storage device showing a maximum capacity of zero bytes? 

Comment: My best suggestion is that the installation of TF2 (Team Fortress) caused an issue where your log files filled incredibly quick, and you then ran out of disk space. You should probably boot a live USB, and inspect `/var/log`, and then remove large log files. However, if you choose to reinstall, you could just format the disk and start from scratch.

Comment: start a live session, free up some space and then you can boot again :)

Comment: Also to clarify, disk space cannot be "deleted", unless you have a hardware malfunction.

Comment: When you go for ubuntu installation, there is an option called Try Ubuntu. Try it and see if you are able to see the hard disk once it boots in try mode. If still nothing showing, try opening terminal and run df -h and share the output.

Comment: Wasn’t able to see it. Tried the command and shared it up into the original post, thanks!

Comment: Your provided output mentions COW (*copy on write*) which looks like *live* media, and not an installed system.